# Signing an iOS app in MS app center to work on aws device farm

Tags: appium, visual-studio-app-center, aws-device-farm, wdio-v5, courgette

I'm relatively new to app development, but basically i'm trying to build an ipa file in MS VS app center that will install on the real devices that are on AWS device farm. I'm guessing this should be possible.

The problem I'm getting is that the WebDriverAgent doesn't seem to be installing and I'm getting an ECONNRESET error when running my tests. Appium is definitely running but I guess it can't talk to the device. I may have two issues here but I guess I first need to find out if it's possible before I progress any further. Any help appreciated.

Comment: What else are you seeing in the appium logs and does the built app run on a local device? There are some configuration settings that cause tests to fail when an app is built for a simulator but run against a real device. Also, you can post a run url on the [AWS Device Farm forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=193&start=0) for more help on the issue.

Comment: Please update the question with appium logs.

Answer (score 0):

I work for the AWS Device Farm team.

This should be possible where you take the app built with app center and use the AWS CLI/SDK to schedule test runs on AWS Device Farm.

In this case, were you using Standard environment or custom environment for Appium tests? We recommend using custom environment unless your use case needs individual test artifacts for each test separated out (logs, videos for each test).

Custom environment also lets you switch between multiple Appium versions so that you can test locally first and then test the same setup on Device Farm. The service will also pick up the matching WDA for the Appium version you choose.

Hope this helps.